# Is there a way to get the first base class from inside the class body?

Tags: python, python-3.x

An example to illustrate:

```
class Base:
    value = 'foo'

class Derived(Base):
    value = super().value + 'bar'
```

`super` cannot be called from a class body with no arguments. I'm looking for a generic syntax that can be placed in a class body, regardless of the name of the class or its bases, to get a class attribute from its (first) base class. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, when the class body is being executed, the class itself doesn't exist, so there's nothing you can refer to to get at the base classes.

The only fix I can think of is to name the base class explicitly (e.g. `Base.value` in your example). Since you just named it on the previous line (in the `class` statement), this shouldn't be a huge burden, even if it does require repeating yourself.

It's not very clear *why* you'd want to be able to access a base class from the class body of a derived one. If there is a good reason, you might be able to write some specifically focused metaclass code that would enable it (e.g. you'd assign a magic value to `value` that the metaclass would know means you wanted to look up the base class's value).

Comment: This is what I feared. I know I could do it with the `__prepare__` method of a metaclass, which is called with the list of bases and could insert that list into the namespace of the class body, but I don't want to use a metaclass (to avoid any potential metaclass conflicts later).

Comment: The class itself may not exist, but the base classes listed in the class statement do. Python could have provided some magic variable to refer to the first listed base class, but there would be little benefit, and it might end up not matching the actual first base class when weird metaclasses are involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `metaclass` to set the value of the class variable `value` inside `Derived`:

Maybe something like this:

```
class Base(type):
    value = 'foo'
    def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace):
        self.value = Base.value + self.value

class Derived(metaclass=Base):
    value = 'bar'

Derived.value, Base.value
```

#### output:

```
('foobar', 'foo')
```

Comment: No, this is for Conan, which expects certain class attributes to exist before any constructors are called.